# Formatting html in webgrid

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have a webgrid table as below,

```
  @grid.GetHtml(
        columns: grid.Columns(
          grid.Column("thumb", 
format: @<img src="~/@item.thumb" alt="@item.name"/>),
          grid.Column(format: @<a href="~/Page/@item.name/?id=@item.ID"> <h3 class="blog-page-title">@item.name</h3></a>)


        )
      )
```

I would like to put the name of the column in the second column, and I would also like to add description from the db in the same colums

i did in the code below but doesn't work

@grid.GetHtml(

```
    columns: grid.Columns(
      grid.Column("thumb", format: @<img src="~/@item.thumb" alt="@item.name"/>),
      grid.Column("Items list" format: @<a href="~/Page/@item.name/?id=@item.ID">
 <h3 class="blog-page-title">@item.name</h3></a>
<br/>@item.description
<br/>@item.price)


    )
  )
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?

Answer (score 0):

In order to put multiple top-level tags in an inline helper (`@<...>`), you need to wrap them in `<text>`.